# Reactive rxjs subscribe not running on complete

Tags: angular, typescript, system.reactive, observable

I have DBService typescript class that has this function

```
`initialiseDb(): Observable < any > {


let source = Observable.create((observer) =>
{}

    openRequest.onsuccess = (event: any) =>
    {
        console.log("Database open");
        this.localDb = event.target.result;
    }
    observer.next();
    observer.complete();
});
return source;
```

}

on app.component.ts on ngOnInit

```
let dbInitObservable = this.localDb.initialiseDb().subscribe
        ((res => alert("Initilisation")), err => alert("Error"), () => this.authService.autoSignIn());
```

i need to call the `autoSignIn` from `authService` only on complete after the `initialiseDb` been called and completed.

Any Ideas?, There are no syntax errors but this.authService.autoSignIn() is never getting callled.

Ta.

Comment: Where do you `next` something to this observable?

Comment: just before returning the source

Comment: Yeah that `.next` and `.complete` really need to be inside the `.onsuccess` hook. It's all async code you see.

Comment: spot on Neil, that worked. can i not do 'observer.next(); observer.complete(this.service.autosignIn); ' outside of 'onsuccess' how come that does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the database `open()` inside the callback passed to `Observable.create()`, then you need to listen to the database and emit proper next, error and complete from the listeners.

```
initialiseDb(): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    let openRequest = localDatabase.indexedDB.open(dbName);

    openRequest.onsuccess = (event: any) => {
      console.log("Database open");
      this.localDb = event.target.result;
      observer.next(this.localDb);
      observer.complete();
    }
    openRequest.onerror = (event: any) => {
      console.log("Database error: " + e.target.errorCode);
      observer.error(e.target.errorCode);
    }
  })
}
```